# Japanese characters unable to be decoded from unicode in Python3

Tags: python, unicode

so I have a string "\u00e3\u0081\u00ae\u00e3\u0081\u00bb\u00e3\u0082\u0082" which is suppose to represent the Japanese characters "のほも". For reference, I downloaded this from my Facebook data, and this was a title of one of my chats that was encoded as the above. When I submitted this code to a github app (FBMessageExplorer), it restored the original Japanese string, so I know that it isn't totally wrong.

However, when I try to print this string out in python, I get "ã®ã»ã", so something's going wrong. I looked up the unicode characters, and apparently "のほも" should be represented as "\u306e\u307b\u3082", and this does work in python. But I don't know how the github app can restore the unicode expression above to Japanese text, when it doesn't seem to be the exact unicode string? I'm really confused.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like you shouldn't have that string in the first place. Like you decoded it with the wrong encoding. Use the correct encoding instead.

Comment: @Heap I've heard repeatedly that Facebook exports things wrong; but have no idea about the validity of that myself…

Comment: @deceze Unless they're using some Python code provided by Facebook, I think it's not the fault of the data but the fault of the OP's Python code.

Comment: It's really the fault of something which thought it was reading Latin-1 when it was in fact reading UTF-8. It may well be on Facebook's side. A lot of "how do I fix UnicodeDecodeError" questions have an answer which suggests to try Latin-1, without explaining how it could make matters worse instead of better.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that original message are the Unicode-escape encoded UTF-8 bytes, instead of the straight Unicode-escaped characters. I.e., The UTF-8 encoding of "の" is `E3 81 AE`. So you must decode that text in multiple steps:

1. Unicode escapes to nonsense characters.
2. Nonsense characters to bytes.
3. Bytes interpreted as UTF-8:

```
>>> "\u00e3\u0081\u00ae\u00e3\u0081\u00bb\u00e3\u0082\u0082".encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
'のほも'
```